# Mount network storage to Axis camera using Windows 7 file share

Tags: nas, ip-camera

I am unable to mount a network share from a win 7 machine to my Axis M1054 ip camera.  The network share works fine when accessing the share from another windows 7 computer, but not from the camera.

The error message on the Axis camera is "Test failed! Error while mounting network share".

I tried turning off the firewall on the Win 7 nas machine.  The security settings on the share folder allow full read/write security permissions and share permissions.

### Axis Camera UI

[image]
[image]

The camera is at IP address 10.71.25.23, and the computer with the NAS can access the cameras web page UI just fine.

As you can see below, the file share is accessible from another windows 7 machine just fine.  And I can even create a test file remotely, showing I have write privileges for the admin user.

[image]

The Axis documentation says:

> Cameras without an SD card can be configured to record to a network
>   share. A network share can be a share on a NAS (Network Attached
>   Storage) or any server that uses CIFS (Common Internet File System).
>   It is possible to add multiple network shares, but only one per
>   camera.

I assumed a Win 7 share folder is the same as CIFS.  Can a windows 7 share folder be a NAS for an Axis camera?  If so, what I might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the date and time were not set correctly in the camera, and this prevented the camera from connecting to the network share.

Solution was to set the date time manually, and then configure ntp for updates.  Connected immediately.

Comment: Didn't help, still cannot create a network share

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old... but I also encountered this same symptom, however the solution was different for me.

**DISCLAIMER**: This solution involves modifying many Windows settings that are probably a high security risk. In my situation, this is not an issue since my PC that is connected to the camera is totally isolated and not on the internet. You've been warned.

Here's what I tried, in order:

---

1. I set up machine as NTP server and set up the camera time properly as @steampowered suggests.

The error persisted.

---

2. Since nowadays Windows doesn't have SMB enabled, you need to enable this manually in optional features.

Run "optionalfeatures" and enable SMB, which requires a restart.

[image]

[image]

Not sure if this was necessary, but I also added SMB1, SMB2, and SMB3 registry entries manually (in HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters).

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3

The error persisted.

---

3. Modify setting in Windows to allow network devices to access network shares. Somehwhere in "advanced network settings", then "all networks", then you need to turn public folder sharing "on".

[image]

Finally, the camera could mount to the share.